# Where and how to save data between sessions for a wpf custom control?

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I am building a custom color picker in WPF and want to save/read the list of recent colors used by the user between different application runs.

Assuming the custom control could be used in multiple applications and in multiple places within the same application, I'd like all the instances of the color picker within the same application to read the same values but this list should be unique for each application its used in.

There are a number of ways to do this. But whats the best practice for persisting data for custom controls (WPF and non WPF)?

Comment: I would save the settings as xml-file in the folder of application. But I don't know if it is a good practice.

Comment: If you mean application data folder, it is.  If you mean the folder the application's installed to, it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way I've found to do this:

1. Create an XML serializable class that contains all of the settings that you want to save as an instance.
2. Create a user-scoped string setting to save the settings in.
3. Deserialize the string setting into the instance of the control-settings class at application startup, and serialize it into the user setting at shutdown.